# get the index.php with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a bunch of ReWrite rules in my .htaccess such as these

`RewriteRule ^brochure/([^/]+)/?$ brochure.php?cat_path=$1`

It's all working great thanks to answers I found by searching this site. But I've got a tiny little snag.

This rule works perfecty at the moment
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ $1.php` It catches all my urls like `www.mysite.com/shane` and requestes `shane.php` - So far so good, but when I call `www.mysite.com` I need it to request `index.php`

Which rule could I use for this?

Thanks people.

UPDATE - For the sake of future users needing similar help.

My rule of `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ $1.php` was causing the problem I mentioned above. The question mark `?` is not needed in this type of rule, when you remove the question mark the index.php file in the directory returns to being the default landing page. Thanks to Tomalak for the Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any rule for it. Just make sure that `.php` default index files for the directory and it'll happen automatically.

**Update**

I think that your rule

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ $1.php
```

should in fact be

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1.php
```

so that it does not conflict with requests where the filename isn't given (which you want to direct to `index.php`).

Comment: Usually on my server, `mysite.com` would request index.php or index.html, however when I'm using my rules stated above, it no longer does. This means your suggestion doesn't work and gives me a 404

Comment: @shane: Use `RewriteLog` and look in the log file.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't your rule be `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1.php`? Your use of `?` seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for,not sure thought:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ index.php
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the moment I use the rules I stated in OP, this rule no longer works. Nor does the usual automatic referring to index.php or index.html. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do as Tomalak says, and ensure the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html) is set to load `index.php`.

Or close to what James says,

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the moment I use the rules I stated in OP, this rule no longer works. Nor does the usual automatic referring to index.php or index.html.

Comment: @shane: That'll be because of the ordering, this would need to go first with the rule you have, also remove the end `?`, it makes the rest optional, which allows it to match the empty case, which is what the above does.

Comment: This worked, but Tomalak was spot on about the miss-use of the ?. His answer allowed me to save a line of code. Thanks.

Comment: @shane: Yes, that is why I mentioned it.  Suggest you learn regex properly, it is a very handy skillset.