# Neither XAMPP or the live website is rendering the index.php automatically

Tags: php, .htaccess

Ever since I added (at least that's when I started to notice something's wrong) an .htaccess file to my root folder with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

my website never landed on the index.php file automatically. To see the live result:
www.unidrones.co.za/ChoiceGelatin

The page is supposed to render the index.php file and automatically highlight the "HOME" link, like it does when I manually type index.php in the URL: www.unidrones.co.za/ChoiceGelatin/index.php

For one, it's reading the index file contents, but the CSS associated with it is not working. Each page has a body ID added dynamically, so the index file's body tag would have an ID of #index.

I've researched on SO and other forums, and seen similar problems, and I checked all as I tried them out:

1. edit the Apache config file (check)
2. remove the # comment from the allowOverrite All (check)
3. edit the htaccess file on cPanel (check)
4. delete the htaccess file (check)
5. place DirectoryIndex index.php in the .htaccess file (check)
6. this question was close but still does not apply [get the index.php with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770507/get-the-index-php-with-htaccess)
7. some other solutions not worth mentioning (check all)

None of the above solutions work. I tried the site on XAMPP and live and neither is displaying as it should, like it always did until yesterday.

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite enabled in the apache http.conf file?

Comment: The only mod_rewrite line in the httpd.conf file is this, and it's not commented out so I assume it is enabled: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 1):

Add an index.php into your root with this content:

```
<?php
header('Location: ' . ('http://www.unidrones.co.za/ChoiceGelatin/index.php'));
?>
```

This will redirect you to the ChoiceGelatin's index page. The rewrite-rule in your .htaccess actually removes the burden of adding `.php` everytime you request for a php-file. It doesn't seem to be working though, probably because of the configuration in http.conf. [Try enabling mod-rewrite!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272731/using-mod-rewrite-with-xampp-and-windows-7-64-bit)

Comment: @ArabianMaiden Both the links render the same php file. The javascript in `scripts.php` is responsible for the styling(class `here` to be specific)

Comment: This is a sensible workaround, however I need to know what I done wrong, because only until yesterday everything was working exactly as it should be... In future I'd much prefer not to use a header() function but instead have it work the way it should

Comment: @ArabianMaiden Well, I am not sure. Perhaps you had a different .htaccess file that would correctly redirect any url to correct locaton and deleted it. Or you had an index page before as well?